# SELECT data from Table3 in case Table1.field='x' else SELECT data from Table2

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, join, case

This must be a rather simple task, have been playing around with SELECT IF / ELSE or CASE, tried a UNION ... all in combination with a JOIN of all tables but so far no result...

## SITUATION:

Table1 contains a lot of information on different kinds of material, in this case cars, trailers and various. All have brands, but when updating the 'brand' field of Table1 it should only offer certain options depending on the kind of material stored in Table1.Kind ...

Table2, Table3 & Table4 is just a 1 column option list of allowed brands (with no relation to Table1) where Table2 contains the car brands, Table3 the trailer brands and Table4 the various brands.

**WHAT IS EXPECTED?**

Working on a PHP script that updates Table1. Depending on the value of Table1.Kind, I want to select all available brand options from Table2 or Table3 or Table4 to present them in Table1.Brand

**Non-SQL example of the drop-down list presented in Table1.Brand:**

```
IF Table1.Kind=('car' OR 'motorhome') then SELECT * FROM Table2
IF Table1.Kind='trailer' then SELECT * FROM Table3
ELSE SELECT * FROM Table4
```

Now just need this translated into MySQL. Anyone great ideas?
To make it easier: was thinking of adding the multiple "Brand" tables into 1 single table with a second column for the "Type"... Don't know if this option is the most favourable seen from a DB perspective?

Comment: It's far from clear what you are asking for here. Perhaps you could provide an example of the data and he expected output.

Comment: Table1 contains:  Kind / Brand / Type / YeaOfBuild / ...

Table2 contains: Brand / Country /  ...

Table3 contains; Brand / Country /  ...

When updating a record in Table1, I want to present an option list for the field Table1.Brand based on Table1.Kind. If Table1.Kind = 'Car' I want to see the different brands from Table2, if Table1.Kind = 'Trailer' I want to see the different brands from Table3 and so on...